# Fingering on sheet music?

Tags: fingering

I'm trying to teach an autistic child the trumpet. He does not read music. Is there any sheet music out there with the fingerings already on it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how advance your student is but the picture below shows the fingerings. It also shows a diagram of a trumpet.

[image: How about that?]